# Does the uncertainty principle affect event horizons?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

I was thinking about black holes. For a simple black hole the event horizon is given by a distance of 2 times mass (energy) of the black hole. (2m).

But according to quantum mechanics, if you try to calculate the energy of a black hole during a very short time frame the energy becomes uncertain. Only over a long time frame can you get a precise energy.

Therefore from that reasoning, does it mean that the event horizon distance is actually fluctuating? And so the black hole is kind of vibrating?

For a black hole when viewed at the scale of the plank time would the horizon be fluctuating on the scale of twice the Planck length?

Does this mean particles can escape from a black hole?

Is that correct?

Comment: The time-energy uncertainty probably does not mean what you think it means, see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/50583).

Comment: Is the black hole is kind of vibrating?=> You can get complex solutions for the Schwarzschild Radius of a Kerr BH. You may interprete them as oscillations, but I think these are forbidden by the Cosmic censorship hypothesis. (Not sure)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Uncertainty Principle and Black Holes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56918/)

Comment: @ACuriousMind. I think it does. A system can "borrow" a certain amount of energy over a short period of time as long as it gives it back. So in that case the black hole energy could fluctuate over small time-scales and so the horizon would also fluctuate right? Probably not really important if it does since a fluctuation of 2 plank lengths is almost non-measurable. Although that "2" could make all the difference.

Comment: @zooby: ACuriousMind is correct. You are being deceived by the layman literature about these things. Quantum systems don't borrow energy and they don't give it back, either. These mentioned "effects" are not physical but they are a misinterpretation of uncertainty and perturbation theory with Feynman diagrams.

Comment: @JohnRennie this question is significantly more specific than the one linked as possible duplicate, and the answers there don't really answer the present question.

Comment: I know they don't literally borrow energy. But that is short-hand way to think about it. My question may be related to Stephen Hawking's recent statement that the event horizon doesn't exist. Or maybe it is unrelated.

Comment: @zooby: it is unrelated. See [this question and answers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95366/why-does-stephen-hawking-say-black-holes-dont-exist).